# Does Lerna bump dependency versions when releasing new versions?

Tags: npm, lerna

If I have a monorepo with `packageA` and `packageB`, with the latter having a dependency on the former. If I then run `lerna version major`, for example, resulting in `packageA`'s version number being bumped, does the listing of the dependency on it in `packageB`'s `package.json` also get bumped automatically, or should that be done manually?

(I tried setting up a test repository to do this, but then Lerna was complaining it didn't have a remote yet, so I'm hoping someone with experience using Lerna knows the answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of this answer, I'm going to assume you are not using conventional Commits. Please feel free to respond with more specifics if I assume wrong.

### TL;DR

Yes, if you run `lerna version major` _all packages in your repo will be updated to a new major version and the `package.json` file for `packageB` will be updated with the new version number for `packageA`.

### Details

Let's say you have your `packageA` and `packageB` packages in your monorepo and they have `package.json` files that look like this:

```json
# packageA/package.json
{
  "name": "packageA",
  "version": "1.0.0,"
}
```

```json
# packageB/package.json
{
  "name": "packageB",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "packageA": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

When you run `lerna version major:

- The `version` field in `packageA/package.json` will update to `2.0.0`
- The `version` field in `packageB/package.json` will update to `2.0.0`
- The `dependencies.packageA` field in `packageB/package.json` will update to `^2.0.0`

```json
# packageA/package.json
{
  "name": "packageA",
  "version": "2.0.0,"
}
```

```json
# packageB/package.json
{
  "name": "packageB",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "packageA": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, and just happens to have become relevant to me again seven months later.

Comment: what happens if there is peerDependency also?